# zoom an image on a coordinate using jquery on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to zoom an JPEG image with predefined image coordinates using `onclick` function.
I already have the set of coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and I just want to zoom on these coordinates with `onclick` button.

Please give me any solution using jquery or ajax.

Comment: AJAX has nothing to do with it.

Comment: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Answer (score 0):

You could always just enlarge the image but keep the container a fixed size e.g:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var coords = '100,100'.split(',');
    $('img').width('400px');
    $('img').css('marginLeft', '-' + coords[0] + 'px');
    $('img').css('marginTop', '-' + coords[1] + 'px');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qy7bA/